# Не выравнивается контент по вертикали flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Не удается равномерно распределить элементы по вертикали, чтобы было пространство между ними, не работает свойство space-between

```css
.option_message{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: space-between;
  height: 170px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left:15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:25px 0;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="option_message">
 <p>Вы точно хотите удалить товар?</p>
 <button class="option_message_btn">Удалить</button>
 <button class="option_message_btn">Отмена</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У свойства `align-items` нет значения `space-between`.
Вам нужно использовать `justify-content: space-between`.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавить:

```
justify-content: space-between;
```